# fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found, when running mpicc cmd on macOS M1

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

When I try to compile an MPI file using `mpicc "srcfile" -o "exfile"` I get the following error:

```
sump.c:3:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

But when I run a normal series code using `gcc` I do not get that error.

**I Believe this is because I changed some paths wrongfully using the following commands:**

```
export PATH="$(brew --prefix llvm)/bin:$PATH";  
export COMPILER=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++   
export CFLAGS="-I /usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include"
export CXXFLAGS="-I /usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include"
export LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -mlinker-version=450"
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Is `stdio.h` installed correctly? Where is it? In `/usr/include`? Can you do a "hello world" program, compiled with `clang++` and `mpicc`? Note that `clang++` is a C++ compiler and not a C compiler. Also, I'd abut the `-I` against the directory (e.g.) `-I dir` --> `-Idir` [may be nothing but ...]. If `stdio.h` is in `/usr/local/include`, you may need: `mpicc -I/usr/local/include "srcfile" -o "exfile"`

Comment: I cannot find stdio.h in /usr/local/include, I can compile a "Hello World" program serially using gcc but this issue appears when I compile using mpicc, This issue appeared after I did the mentioned configuration.

Comment: `mpicc` is a wrapper for a `C` compiler. are you sure it calls the one you expect? If you use Open MPI, you can `mpicc --showme srcfile.c` to see which command line is invoked.

Comment: It helps to know _where_ `stdio.h` is. In `/usr/include` [since it's not in `/usr/local/include`]? What does `find / -name stdio.h` produce? You could run the compilers under the equivalent of `strace gcc ...` and see where `gcc` finds the file (vs. where `mpicc` does _not_ find the file). Also, _if_ `COMPILER` is set to `clang++` instead of `clang`, does this [somehow] affect things in the make? (e.g. the make tells `mpicc` to use `clang++` as its underlying C compiler?)

Comment: Hey, did you solve this error? I have same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You may find that XCode has the headers installed miles away from where your compiler expects it.  I have a script like this:

```sh
# Set GCC environment for macOS Catalina 10.15 (and maybe beyond)

MACOSX_SDK="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk"
export LIBRARY_PATH="$MACOSX_SDK/usr/lib"
export CPATH="$MACOSX_SDK/usr/include"
export MANPATH="$(clnpath $MANPATH:$MACOSX_SDK/usr/share/man)"
```

The `CPATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH` variables allow (home-built) GCC to work.  I don't know whether it will work for your compiler — you may need to set different variables.  The headers are installed under `$CPATH`, though, so you need to figure out how to tell your compiler to look there.  You might be able to set a symlink from under `/usr/local` or `/opt` to the value in `$MACOSX_SDK`, and then set your variables to the shorter path.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the previous answer, I used the command "find / -name stdio.h" to find the location of the files and added the CPATH to the bash config file:

```
MACOSX_SDK="/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools"
export CPATH="$MACOSX_SDK/usr/include"
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting "SDKROOT" helped me resolve the issue. And nothing else worked. My environment: MacOS 14.0, M1, Xcode 15.0.1

```
export SDKROOT=$(xcrun --sdk macosx --show-sdk-path)
```

You can either run it in terminal or add it to .zshrc if there is issue with compiling code through command line or when you install some of the python packages.